# Vite HMR doesn't detect changes to components nested under sub folders

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

In a Vue + Vite project, I have folder structure like this

[image]

The problem is vite doesn't detect changes (ctrl+s) in A.vue or B.vue i.e., components nested under NestedFolder in components folder. Everywhere else works fine.

My vite.config.js looks like this,

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '@public': fileURLToPath(new URL('./public', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'XXX',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,      
        ws: true,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I've tried custom HMR functions as per the vite HMR API docs, got it to send full reload using this.

```
...
plugins: [
    vue(),
    {
      name: 'custom-hmr',
      enforce: 'post',
      // HMR
      handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
        if (file.endsWith('.vue')) {
          console.log('reloading json file...');
  
          server.ws.send({
            type: 'reload',          
            path: '*'
          });
        }
      },
    }
  ], ...
```

I looked through vite's HMR API docs but couldn't figure out how to send update event to vite when using custom hmr function

Any help/suggestion on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-ecc14l?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FNestedFolder%2FB.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FNestedFolder%2FA.vue). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: Which version of Vite are you using in your project? I suspect updating to the latest stable version may resolve your issue. You may need to refactor your configuration to the latest too.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, too. Please provide more information.

Comment: @tony19 I tried to reproduce the problem on stackblitz and codesandbox but couldn't. It's helpful to know that this is not default behavior. I assumed I needed to configure it for nested folders. The project is really huge. Maybe some other package is interfering with vite configuation. Thank you.

Comment: @JStanton I'm using v3.0.1

Answer (score 6):

Ok I solved the problem. The problem is not with nested folders.
Vite seems to ignore components that are imported with absolute path.

E.g. Vite doesn't detect changes in components imported as:

```
import Dropdown from '@/components/GlobalDropdown.vue'
//@ resolves to /src
```

but detects changes in imports that are relative:

```
import LoadingSpinner from '../LoadingSpinner.vue'
```

I couldn't find any setting that addresses this. But having relative paths for component imports solved the issue. Is this an issue?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my HMR not updating.

Comment: For me it was a case sensitive typo as mentioned in the answer below! (I'm using aliases and it's working)

Answer (score 4):

I think issue is that you made a caseSensitive typo, please check that your path is correct, I had similar issue and this was one letter typed in uppercase.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yep. My import statement in code was all lowercase, but my nested folder name mistakenly had an uppercase letter.

Comment: It was not a case sensitive typo. The problem was solved by using not using alias imports as mentioned below. Thank you.